# Selenide-How to maximise the browser window

Tags: selenide

After Selenide 6.0.1 version they deleted Configuration.startMaximized. How can we maximize browser now?

Comment: Selenide does not maximize browser by default
At the beginning it seemed to be a good idea to open browser to the full screen size. It should make tests stable: more elements fit to the screen. Many people still think this way.
Actually it makes tests flaky because tests result depends on screen size which is a random uncontrollable variable. Our new recommendation to set browser size explicitly to the minimal size supported by your application.
[Released Selenide 5.0.0](https://selenide.org/2018/10/10/selenide-5.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the next:

```
getWebDriver().manage().window().maximize();
```

**getWebDriver()** - the static method from **com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner**

For example:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Browsers;
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver;

public class DriverManager {

    public static void initDriver() {
        Configuration.browser = Browsers.FIREFOX;
        open();
        getWebDriver().manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the pre-defined size of the browser, it helps you to avoid unexpected behavior in tests, especially on remote runs.

```
 Configuration.browserSize = "1920x1080";
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to open target page:

```
Selenide.open("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Than you can maximize window with this code:

```
WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().manage().window().maximize();
```